# Is it normal to need to restart Solr/Apache regularly?

Tags: solr

It seems like about once every 2 to 3 months or so something about our solr implementation breaks down. Most recently the process we use to reindex our solr cores broke. It's a console application that just does two things: 1) Clear the indexes, 2) Rebuild the indexes. That's it, and it just does it by issuing http web requests to the server.

I was getting a 500 response when it was trying to clear the 1st core. None of the other cores had a problem though (except for the fact that they came after the 1st one and it is a synchronous process so nothing got reindexed). I spent a little time troubleshooting but ultimately I just restarted apache and it worked.

That seems to be the solution for everything. I wish I could remember previous issues I've run into, but something a little different seems to happen each time and it's always just much easier to reset apache than to spend the time to troubleshoot (plus it always happens in production and so spending hours troubleshooting isn't really a good option if I can fix it in seconds).

I wish these issues happened in staging or development where I could take time to investigate further, but it's always in production. So I'm starting to wonder if I should just create a task to reset Apache server every night.

When I reset it and it just suddenly works normally without me having to make a single change, I really have to wonder about the stability of Solr. Is this normal for others who use solr?

Comment: What does the stack trace in the log say when you get the 500 error? That could give you a hint to where the issue is coming from. Upgrading to a more recent version of Solr might also be a necessity, as there is always plenty of fixes (and new features) coming - both on Lucene and Solr. We have Solr installations running without interaction for years at a time, so it's not a rule - but there can always be issues, such as problems in external database drivers (if you're using DIH) or other external components as well.